# How to prove $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{1-xyz}=\zeta(3)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

The triple integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{1-xyz}=\zeta(3) \dots (1)$$
is not separable in $x,y,z$ and the integral representation of reciprocal: $\frac{1}{1-xyz}=\int_{0}^{1} t^{-xyz} dt$ also doesn't help separation of the integrand. I want help to prove (1).

Comment: $1+xyz+(xyz)^2+(xyz)^3+\ldots$, if you can control the bit near $(1,1,1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expand out as a geometric progression. You get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1x^n y^nz^n\,dx\,dy\,dz.$$
Now do the integral.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{1-xyz}=
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ln(1-yz)}{yz} dy dz =\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z} \frac{\ln(1-u)}{u} \frac{du dz}{z}, u=yz$$
$$ \implies I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{z}[1+u/2+u^2/3+u^3/4+....]\frac{ du  dz}{z}= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k-1}}{k^2} dz= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}=\zeta(3).$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx dy dz}{1-xyz}&=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln u}{1-uz}dudz\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (uz)}{1-uz}dudz\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 v}{1-v}dv\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times 2\zeta(3)\\
&=\boxed{\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

NB: i have used the following results: If $f$ is a continuous function on $[0;1]$ then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(xy)dxdy=-\int_0^1 f(z)\ln zdz$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx=2\zeta(3)$