# Evaluating definite triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to explicitely evaluate the triple integral

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xyz} dx dy dz.$$

Using geometric sum expansion, it is almost straightforward to show that the integral is equal to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$
or, in other words, $\zeta(3)$ or Apéry’s constant.

I am wondering if there is another way how to evaluate the integral and get the result in a different form. Thanks a lot in advance for any helpful tips!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837548/how-to-prove-int-01-int-01-int-01-fracdx-dy-dz1-xyz-zet?noredirect=1

Comment: Hi FDP, it unfortunately does not help me a lot. My question is, whether there is another way to evaluate the integral (such as the way with result $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for alike double integral).

Comment: There is no special value known for $\zeta(3)$, i mean for $\zeta(2)$ there is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ but no such value is known for $\zeta(3)$.

Comment: Maybe : $\zeta (3)=-\frac{\psi ^{(2)}(1)}{2}=\text{Li}_3(1)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xyz} dx dy dz\\
&\overset{u(z)=xyz}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{xy}\left(\int_0^{xy}\frac{1}{1-u}du\right)dxdy\\
&=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-xy)}{xy}dxdy\\
&\overset{v(y)=xy}=-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}dv\right)dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\underbrace{\left[\ln x\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}dv\right)\right]_0^1}_{=0}+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\Big[\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)\Big]_0^1}_{=0}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}_{=2\zeta(3)}\\
&=\boxed{\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

NB:
I assume,

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx=2\zeta(3)\end{align}